# Codeigniter Ion Auth configuration

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

I am using Ion Auth for registration, and everything is working fine on local, So when I wanted to move Live server I need email activation for new registrations [I am not using SMTP, there is no email config file in my config folder], So I made changes in ion_auth.php in config file as follows::

```
$config['email_activation']           = TRUE; 
$config['manual_activation']          = FALSE; 
$config['use_ci_email'] = TRUE;
```

as far as I know about this library (I am new to CodeIgniter), that's it. But unfortunately these configurations are not taking effect. When I var dump the following items inside constructor of ion_auth.php library file returns null

```
$this->config->item('use_ci_email','ion_auth') or
$this->config->item('email_activation','ion_auth')
```

And other config items like 'admin_email' has no issues, I can fetch the value. So, what is wrong with my config file, I am using very basic file provided by the library repo.

When I set the values, inside the constructor of library file as below, it works.

```
$this->config->set_item('use_ci_email', TRUE);
$this->config->set_item('email_activation', TRUE);
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing to get this weird behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I opened an issue on Ion Auth Git repo, and the Author, Ben Edmunds  responded with the solution, If anybody facing this issue, with latest CodeIgniter, please pull the latest commit of IonAuth library and test, It will work.

For more on the issue, please refer the isse,
[Codeigniter Ion Auth configuration and Email Activation](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/issues/1024#issuecomment-276667795)